# How to set the precision and scale of decimal return type in Spark UDF?

Tags: apache-spark

Here is my sample code. I am expecting decimal(16,4) as return type from the UDF, but it is decimal(38,18).

Is there any better solution?

I am NOT expecting the answer "cast(price as decimal(16,4))", as I have some other business logic in my UDF other than just casting.

Thanks in advance.

```
import scala.util.Try
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.Decimal
val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[*]").appName("Test").getOrCreate()
import spark.implicits._

val stringToDecimal = udf((s:String, precision:Int, scale: Int) => {
  Try(Decimal(BigDecimal(s), precision, scale)).toOption
})

spark.udf.register("stringToDecimal", stringToDecimal)

val inDf = Seq(
  ("1", "864.412"),
  ("2", "1.600"),
  ("3", "2,56")).toDF("id", "price")

val outDf = inDf.selectExpr("id", "stringToDecimal(price, 16, 4) as price")
outDf.printSchema()
outDf.show()

------------------output----------------
root
  |-- id: string (nullable = true)
  |-- price: decimal(38,18) (nullable = true)

+---+--------------------+
| id|               price|
+---+--------------------+
|  1|864.4120000000000...|
|  2|1.600000000000000000|
|  3|                null|
+---+--------------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spark associates `Decimal` with `decimal(38, 18)`. You need an explicit cast

```
$"price".cast(DataTypes.createDecimalType(32,2))
```

Comment: Thank you, implemented casting on top of the udf call.

Answer (score 3):

As for Spark 3.0 and below, you can't set precision and scale in decimal returned by a Spark user defined function (UDF) as the precision and scale are erased at UDF's creation.

#### Explanation

To create an UDF, either by calling function `udf` with a lambda/function as argument or by directly registering the lambda/function as UDF by using `sparkSession.udf.register` method, Spark needs to convert arguments types and returns type of the lambda/function to [Spark's DataType](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/content/spark-sql-DataType.html)

To do so, Spark will use method `schemaFor` in class [ScalaReflection](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/ScalaReflection.scala) to map scala types to Spark's DataType.

For the `BigDecimal` or the `Decimal` type, the mapping is done as follow:

```scala
case t if isSubtype(t, localTypeOf[BigDecimal]) =>
  Schema(DecimalType.SYSTEM_DEFAULT, nullable = true)
case t if isSubtype(t, localTypeOf[java.math.BigDecimal]) =>
  Schema(DecimalType.SYSTEM_DEFAULT, nullable = true)
case t if isSubtype(t, localTypeOf[Decimal]) =>
  Schema(DecimalType.SYSTEM_DEFAULT, nullable = true)
```

Meaning that when your lambda/function returns either a `BigDecimal` or a `Decimal`, the return type of the UDF will be [DecimalType.SYSTEM_DEFAULT](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/types/DecimalType$.html#SYSTEM_DEFAULT:org.apache.spark.sql.types.DecimalType). `DecimalType.SYSTEM_DEFAULT` type is a `Decimal` with a precision of 38 and a scale of 18 :

```scala
val MAX_PRECISION = 38
...
val SYSTEM_DEFAULT: DecimalType = DecimalType(MAX_PRECISION, 18)
```

#### Conclusion

Thus, every time you transform a lambda or a function that returns a `Decimal` or a `BigDecimal` to a Spark's UDF, the precision and scale are erased with the default precision of 38 and scale of 18.

So your only way is to follow [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61097025/6807769) and cast returned value of UDF when calling it

Answer (score 0):

For pyspark use:

```py
from pysprak.sql.types import DecimalType
def your_func(value):
    ...
spark.udf.register("your_func", your_func, DecimalType(precision=25, scale=10))
```