# In a Scala notebook on Apache Spark Databricks how do you correctly cast an array to type decimal(30,0)?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, aws-databricks

I am trying to cast an array as Decimal(30,0) for use in a select dynamically as:

```
WHERE array_contains(myArrayUDF(), someTable.someColumn)
```

However when casting with:

```
val arrIds = someData.select("id").withColumn("id", col("id")
                .cast(DecimalType(30, 0))).collect().map(_.getDecimal(0))
```

Databricks accepts that and signature however already looks wrong to be:
intArrSurrIds: Array[java.math.BigDecimal] = Array(2181890000000,...)     // ie, a BigDecimal

Which results in the below error:

Error in SQL statement: AnalysisException: cannot resolve.. due to data type mismatch: Input to function array_contains should have been array followed by a value with same element type, but it's [array<decimal(38,18)>, decimal(30,0)]

How do you correctly cast as decimal(30,0) in Spark Databricks Scala notebook instead of decimal(38,18) ?

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make `arrIds` an `Array[Decimal]` using the code below:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{Decimal, DecimalType}

val arrIds = someData.select("id")
  .withColumn("id", col("id").cast(DecimalType(30, 0)))
  .collect()
  .map(row => Decimal(row.getDecimal(0), 30, 0))
```

However, it will not solve your problem because you lose the precision and scale once you create your user defined function, [as I explain in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64687530/6807769)

To solve your problem, you need to cast the column `someTable.someColumn` to Decimal with the same precision and scale than the UDF returned type. So your `WHERE` clause should be:

```sql
WHERE array_contains(myArray(), cast(someTable.someColumn as Decimal(38, 18)))
```

Comment: Thanks Vincent! Would it be possible as per previous link you mentioned to recast the UDF explicitly to Decimal(30,0) ?  (Rather than the other way around..?) so Eg: val arrayDecIdsUdf = () => intArrSurrIds.cast(DataTypes.createDecimalType(30,0)) // recast here?
spark.udf.register("myUDF", arrayDecIdsUdf)

Comment: No, because when you create the UDF you erase the Decimal precision and scale.  The erasure takes place in `spark.udf.register` method, so every precision and scale changes you do before is useless